# China's new little car aka "The Highway Suppository" by VW

Tags: meaning, slogan

> [China's New "Little Car" aka "The Highway Suppository](http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/708448-chinas-new-little-car-aka-the-highway-suppository/)"
>   Here's a one seater car that will get you back around on the cheap.  This $600 Volkswagen's car gets 258 mpg, 109.687 km/l or 0.9 litre per 100 km!!!
>   <sub>source: Thai Visa.com</sub>

[image]

What does *suppository* mean in this context?

Comment: When you looked up "suppository" in the dictionary, what did you find?

Comment: Please supply more context. A link to the article (with a photo of the car) would be helpful. The sentence might be using "suppository" in reference to the shape of the car, or to something else.

Comment: A bit of a reality check:  the article about the supposedly 1-seat, 258-mpg, $600 car has been circulating since at least 2009. It is loosely based on the VW L-1 concept car (1liter per 100 km). The L-1 was a two-seater and had a projected price around $25k.  http://www.truthorfiction.com/vwl1/  So it's more like somebody pulling "facts" out of their ass. Maybe that's why it's "suppository"—the story depends on a number of false _suppositions_!

Comment: I'm very tempted to downvote because it doesn't take much effort to say "where" you found the quote, and to provide a minimum amount of context e.g. a photo. But I am voting to close for lack of basic research.

Comment: What is the Chinese name for this car?  I have a feeling that Highway Suppository was translated from Chinese SaiJi which in English can mean suppository but can also refer to a medicine that relieves constipation or fevers.  The idea could mean it's a Highway Relief...although I'm not sure that makes sense as a one-seater is just going to create more cars on the highway.

Comment: @Mari-LouA see my comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is saying that their new little car is like a pill (both little), to the crowded highways. Just as we use a suppository for a solution to constipation (crowded poop), this is a small solution to the crowded highways.

Comment: An interesting conjecture, but have you any source or justification for that explanation?  In AmE a laxative might be in suppository form, but if it is, we would not call it a "pill".  Could the "suppository" perhaps literally refer to the shape of the car, rather than metaphorically to a purgative effect?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I mentioned that it is referring to the car. I said they are both little, which they are. Also, look at the first sentence of this: http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-56185/adult-suppositories-rectal/details and also look up the meaning of "suppository"... "a solid medical preparation in a roughly conical or cylindrical shape." I imagine that's describing a pill.

Comment: I'm with Brian Hitchcock on this one. It's very likely that it means that it 'relieves highway constipation' but I think we need to wait for more context from the OP before we can be sure.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you don't need more context from the OP, just look up the car and look up it's function. lol

Comment: Well, in USA we don't put a "pill" up our ass. So there is a difference.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock of course you do, I'm in the USA... it's called rectal administration.

Comment: @MichaelRader - Let's not get into an argument. On Stack Exchange, users are asked to provide their own research and give proper context when posing a question. That's what Brian H did in his first comment under the question itself. Otherwise we simply encourage people to ask lazy questions.

Comment: Suppositories don't relieve constipation, they are for hemorrhoids.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, as mentioned above, please read this http://www.webmd.com/drugs/2/drug-56185/adult-suppositories-rectal/details

Comment: @MichaelRader would it be better to say that the commonly held idea of suppository is for hemorrhoids?  In any case see my comment to the original question about the Chinese translation

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, someone was struck by the car's extremely rounded lines and small size, and for some reason "suppository"

[image]

sprang to mind. The verbal image is striking enough that the usage has caught on.